# how to extract the values from json data from kafka messages which is not separated by comma

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to read the Kafka topic using streaming and extract the values which is of json format.  I have the below messages in Kafka topic in json format but it is not separated with comma.

How can I extract the values of id and messages:

```
{
    "id":"20168374652257"
    "message":"testFromPubSub2018_09_18_22"
}
```

I have tried the below code but it gives null values as its not separated by comma:

```
val kafka_data =df.select($"value" cast "string" as "value").
      select(get_json_object($"value", "$.id").as("id"),
        get_json_object($"value", "$.message").as("message"))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: if there is no comma then it would not be a valid json message.kindly use a json validator to verify

Comment: Is `get_json_object` throwing any error?

Comment: its not throwing any error.am getting null values.